# Make a relation of a table with three different category of id's table

Tags: database-design, relational-theory

I have an issue 
There a table that's called "Routing" this table is for routing a task for three category of object 
      -

1. Analyser (interne machine)
         -
2. subcontractor (externe )
3. Manually (interne worker)

how to design a relation between 5 tables

```
   1 - task table -> Routing table -> - analyser table
                                      - subcontractor table 
                                      - Interne user table
```

---

**Edit:**, answers to questions in comments:

- Can a task have many routings? Can a routing belong to many tasks or just one?
  No, a `task` is routed to one `routing` (the routing is the manner to know where the task should be done).
- Is there an Analyzer, a Subcontractor and an Interne (ManualWorker) table?
  Yes, there is an `analyser` table, and `subcontractor` table, and `interne` table.
- Can an analyser be part of many routings (of the same task)?
  Yes, an `analyser` can be a part of many `routing`.
- Can a subcontractor take part in many routings of the same task?
  No, a `subcontractor` (or `analyser` or `interne`) take to one `routing` of the `task` (the task is routed to one subctr, or analyser or in interne).

Comment: The relationships are not clear. Can a task have many routings? Can a routing belong to many tasks or just one? Is there an `Analyzer`, a `Subcontractor` and an `Interne (ManualWorker)` table? Can an analyser be part of many routings (of the same task)? Can a subcontractor take part in many routings of the same task? ...

Comment: no a task is routed to one routing (the routing is the manner to know where the task should be done), yes there is an analyser table, and subcontractor table, and interne table. yes an analyser can be a part of many routing. no  a subcontacrctor (or analyser or interne) take to one routing of the task (the task is routed to one subctr, or analyser or in interne

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood what you need is:

**TASK TABLE**: *ID, NAME, DESCR and other attributes*

**ROUTING TABLE**: *ID, IDTASK, INFO and other attributes**

**ANALYSER TABLE**: *ID, IDROUTING and other attributes*

**SUBCONTRACTOR TABLE**: *ID, IDROUTING and other attributes*

**INTERNE USER TALBE**: *ID, IDROUTING and other attributes*

if you want to trace better the relations, you can add in **ROUTING TABLE** also 3 foreign key like *IDANALYSER*, *IDSUBCONTRACTOR* and *IDINTERNEUSER*. This is not very efficient, because you will have always 2 values null and only one with a value.

But, you can go straight from **ROUTING TABLE** to the **right detailed table**.

Comment: But we can have, for example,  the same analyser (or subcontractor) for different task so id routing is not the right place, so the issue is to have a schema that from rout and task know where the task should be done

Comment: so, I think you need a many to many relation...